# HorizontalScrollView difficulties

Tags: android, layout, horizontalscrollview

I made a horizontalscrollview and inside a linearlyout , in this linear layout i put other layouts with different layout_weight , my problem it doesnt do this weight correct ,i set weightsum 3 ,but it just fills like wrap_content

http://postimg.org/image/ds4lstkyt/

```
<HorizontalScrollView
            android:id="@+id/horizontal_scroll_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="3"
                >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                    android:paddingRight="15dp"
                    android:paddingTop="15dp">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="45dp"
                        android:layout_height="45dp"
                        android:paddingBottom="20dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:text="Android"
                            android:textSize="12sp" />
                    </LinearLayout>


                </LinearLayout>

                <View
                    android:layout_width="1dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"

                    android:background="#d9d9d9" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                    android:paddingRight="15dp"
                    android:paddingTop="15dp">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="45dp"
                        android:layout_height="45dp"
                        android:paddingBottom="20dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="IOS" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <View
                    android:layout_width="1dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                    android:background="#d9d9d9" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                    android:paddingRight="15dp"
                    android:paddingTop="15dp">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="45dp"
                        android:layout_height="45dp"
                        android:paddingBottom="20dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="Windows\nPhone" />


                </LinearLayout>

                <View
                    android:layout_width="1dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                    android:background="#d9d9d9" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                    android:paddingRight="15dp"
                    android:paddingTop="15dp">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="45dp"
                        android:layout_height="45dp"
                        android:paddingBottom="20dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="BlackBerry" />


                </LinearLayout>

                <View
                    android:layout_width="1dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                    android:background="#d9d9d9" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                    android:paddingRight="15dp"
                    android:paddingTop="15dp">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="45dp"
                        android:layout_height="45dp"
                        android:paddingBottom="20dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="Budget\nPhones" />


                </LinearLayout>

                <View
                    android:layout_width="1dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                    android:background="#d9d9d9" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                    android:paddingRight="15dp"
                    android:paddingTop="15dp">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="45dp"
                        android:layout_height="45dp"
                        android:paddingBottom="20dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="Tablets" />


                </LinearLayout>

                <View
                    android:layout_width="1dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                    android:background="#d9d9d9" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                    android:paddingRight="15dp"
                    android:paddingTop="15dp">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="45dp"
                        android:layout_height="45dp"
                        android:paddingBottom="20dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="Jewelry &amp;\nWatch" />


                </LinearLayout>

                <View
                    android:layout_width="1dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                    android:background="#d9d9d9" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                    android:paddingRight="15dp"
                    android:paddingTop="15dp">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="45dp"
                        android:layout_height="45dp"
                        android:paddingBottom="20dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="Health &amp;\nBeauty" />
                </LinearLayout>


            </LinearLayout>
        </HorizontalScrollView>
```

Any advises , ideas ??

Comment: So you want what is inside the LinearLayout inside HorizontalScrollView to be set in 3 even parts ?

Comment: yes , its width to be 1/3 of the screen

Comment: But you have 8 LinearLayouts inside that LinearLayout. What is to be done with them? Do you want their View to be 1/3 of the screen?

Comment: i want each layout from those 8 LinearLayouts  to have weight 1/3 of the screen

Comment: I think I understand. You want each of the phone types to span 1/3 of the viewable screen right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use android:fillViewport="true" in your HorizontalScrollView and it will fill up the screen because scrollview is ignore the layout weight.

I hope it will help you!!